# Cannot collect trace from standalone collector

Tags: intellitrace

When I try to run following from command prompt launched as admininstrator

> C:\IntelliTraceCollector\IntelliTraceSC.exe
>   /cp:"C:\IntelliTraceCollector\collection_plan.ASP.NET.default.xml"
>   /f:"C:\IntelliTraceLogs\test.itrace" "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\XYZ\MyApp.exe"

I get following.

> error : Unknown command 'C:\program files (x86)\xyz\myapp.exe'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what *IntelliTrace* should actually do i.e. you dodn't specify a command. You have the following possibilities:

- stop - Stop a logger.
- help -                 Provide help on a particular command
- status -               Names of currently running loggers for the active session
- launch -               Launch an application and begin collecting trace debugging information.
- run -                  Run the logger.
- start -                Start a logger in the background.

This list is displayed by *IntelliTraceSC.exe* if you run it without parameters.

To sum up, you command should probably look in this way:

> C:\IntelliTraceCollector\IntelliTraceSC.exe 
>   launch 
>   /cp:"C:\IntelliTraceCollector\collection_plan.ASP.NET.default.xml" 
>   /f:"C:\IntelliTraceLogs\test.itrace" 
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\XYZ\MyApp.exe"

I added *launch* parametr just after *IntelliTraceSC.exe*.

Comment: I don't want to launch the process, its already running and issue is reproducible. It takes hours (if not days) for the issue to reproduce.

Comment: @paul deter - Since VS 2015 IntelliTrace can attach to already running process. However, there are limitations and I don't know if the standalone collector can also do that. For details see this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/05/14/intellitrace-in-visual-studio-enterprise-2015-now-supports-attach/